# Apache shows 403 error when it runs with including ">" urls

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, web, url-rewriting

My apache rewrite module works fine on other path. but the path which including ">" urls return error.
ex) http://aaa.com/main (o), [http://aaa.com/main>store](http://aaa.com/main%3Estore) (X, 403 Forbidden)

I tries three days but i can't fix it and I can't take gt brackets out.
so i need to know what's the problem is and how to fix it. pls help me.

I think it's not helpful to answer. but repository is down here:
https://github.com/FNBase/FNBase-Engine

Comment: Did you try url encoding? which will output as http://aaa.com/main%3Estore

Comment: HTML characters like `<` and `>` are not allowed in URL for security reasons and you should encode them using their hex equivalent.

Comment: https://perishablepress.com/stop-using-unsafe-characters-in-urls/